# F# - public literal

Tags: f#

Is there a way to define a public literal (public const in C#) on a type?  Apparently let bindings in types must be private and the Literal attribute can't be applied to members.

Answer (score 9):

Use the [< Literal >] attribute. This does the magic you are looking for. In addition, putting the literal attribute on a value such as a string enables it to be used within pattern matching. For example:

```
// BAD - introduces new value named 'Name'
let Name = "Chris Smith"

match Console.ReadLine() with
| Name -> printfn "You entered my name! %s" Name
| _ -> printfn "You didn't enter my name"

// Good - uses the literal value, matches against the value Name
[<Literal>]
let NameLiteral = "Chris Smith"
match Console.ReadLine() with
| NameLiteral -> "You entered my name!"
| _ -> printfn "You didn't enter my name.
```

Edit: I see that the question is referring to how to put these within custom classes (and not modules). I do not know if you can expose a public const / public readonly field within F#, I'll look into it.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, the key is 'public'.

Comment: Not sure why this response keeps getting voted up since it doesn't answer the question (a fact Chris even acknowledges).

Comment: My theory is that people often up-vote when they find something interesting even if it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Daniel, I don't think there is. Is there a specific API you are trying to program against which requires a public field literal?

Comment: Chris, no there isn't. I'm creating a class which in C# I would have given a public const string. I can't seem to find something similar in F#.