# How to define type member constant in F#?

Tags: .net, f#, constants

In C# one can define a type member constant like this:

```
class Foo { public const int Bar = 600; }
```

The IL looks like this.

```
.field public static literal int32 Bar = int32(600)
```

How can I do the same within Visual F# / FSharp?

I tried this to no avail:

```
[<Sealed>]
 type Foo() =

    [<Literal>]
    let Bar = 600
```

Comment: I asked this question -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834923/f-public-literal -- and Chris Smith indicated it's not possible.

Answer (score 24):

I did a couple of experiments with the F# compiler and here are some my observations. If you want to create IL literal, then you need to place the value marked as a `Literal` inside a module. For example like this:

```
module Constants = 
  [<Literal>]
  let Num = 1
```

As a side-note, I did a quick search through the F# specification and it seems that literals can be very useful for pattern matching, because you can use them as a pattern (as long as they start with an uppercase letter):

```
open Constants
match 1 with
| Num -> "1"
| _ -> "other"
```

Now, the question is, why `Literal` doesn't behave as you would expect when you place it inside a type declaration. I think the reason is that `let` declaration inside an F# type declaration cannot be public and will be visible only inside the class/type. I believe that both C# and F# inline literal values when you use them and this is done inside type declarations too. However since the literal cannot be public, there is no reason for generating the `literal` IL field, because nobody could ever access it.

Comment: In C# the literals will be inlined in the bytecode, but the const field will still be there for other types to be used.

Comment: Yes - in F# the `field` will be generated if the literal is public (e.g. in a module) and can be used by someone; if it is visible only inside the class, there is no point generating the bytecode, because other types can't use it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that this is possible.  In fact, I don't even think that you can create immutable public fields, not to mention constants.

Comment: I believe you can create public immutable fields using the `val` declaration and explicit initialization in the constructor written using `new()`, but that wouldn't work for constants, because `val` fields are initialized in the constructor.

Comment: @Tomas - I think that you'll find that your suggestion actually results in a property being defined, rather than a field.  Using a `val mutable` does result in a mutable field, however.

Comment: You're right. public `val` results in a property with a private field (the motivation is to forbid possible C# users of the class from modifying a field that should be immutable).