# How do I use function parameter as literal for pattern matching in F#?

Tags: f#

How do I write a match function that takes two strings and compares them with each other? Right now I just have this. The first one does not work. Is there a better way?

```
let matchFn ([<Literal>]matchString) (aString : string) = match aString with
                                                            matchString -> true
                                                            | _ -> false

let matchFn (matchString : string) (aString : string) = match aString with
                                                          _ when (matchString = aString) -> true
                                                          | _ -> false
```

Answer (score 4):

In this specific case, you could of course just write `aString = matchString`, but I suppose you are asking about the general case. Literals are allowed only on the module level, and they must have a simple constant expression on their right side ([source](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597595)).

However, you can use an active pattern for cases like this. For example (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890037/f-literal-attribute-not-working/3890096#3890096)):

```
let (|Equals|_|) expected actual = 
  if actual = expected then Some() else None
```

and then use it like this:

```
let matchFn (matchString : string) (aString : string) =
   match aString with
   | Equals matchString -> true
   | _ -> false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a guarded match:

```
let matchFn matchString (aString : string) = match aString with
                                                 x when x = matchString -> true
                                                 | _ -> false
```

or, perhaps more idiomatically:

```
let matchFn (matchString:string) = function
    | x when x = matchString -> true
    | _ -> false
```